# Possible to create a separate watchkit app in unity3d?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, watchkit

Apparently, unity3d doesn't support iWatch.  I am not sure if this is possible to create a native watchkit app in your xcode and bridge it to your unity3d app. Anyone know? If yes, how is the general approach to that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to make a bridge between the two, although I don't believe it is quick or simple. Use this as a starting point: http://devgallery.com/unity/watchkit-unity/

Comment: Thanks very much. It seems like what I'm looking for.